# Besides getting better performance, why do we need to use find() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find

I'm aware of that using find may get a better performace when searching for elements

`$('#parent').find('.child');` > `$('#parent .child');`

But are there any conditions that we **must** use `find()` instead of `selector`?

---

And why are people voting to close this question?

find() must have a specific reason to be created and I just want to know why.

Comment: That's not `context`. `context` is a second argument to `$()`.

Comment: @BoltClock is that called selector?

Comment: Suppose that we have a function that is passed `$('#some-id')` as an argument. Since you can't go back and alter the call, you should instead call `find` on the selection to further narrow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` is most useful when you already have the parent DOM element or parent jQuery element.  I often see it used like this in an event handler:

```
$(".whatever").click(function() {
    // change the label in this section to red
    $(this).closest("section").find("label").css("color", "red");
});
```

Or, it's useful when, for other reasons, you already have a jQuery object and you want to just find children in it and operate on them, particularly involving chained operations:

```
// jQuery object previously built for other reason
var items = ...;
// find all child labels and remove a class
items.closest(".item").find("label").removeClass("active");
```

While, it's probably possible to avoid the `.find()` method entirely by using the optional context parameter in a jQuery constructor, it's not as convenient and doesn't lend itself as well to chaining and, half of what jQuery is here for in the first place is to make things quicker and easier so we have `.find()`.